# How can I know, how many EditText user add?

Tags: java, android

I inflate an EditText and I `setId(i++)` | `static int i = 0;`

and this is the code :

```
 buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {




            LayoutInflater layoutInflater =
                    (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            final View addOne = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
            final EditText textOut = (EditText)addOne.findViewById(R.id.textout);
            Button buttonRemove = (Button)addOne.findViewById(R.id.remove);
            buttonRemove.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    ((LinearLayout) addOne.getParent()).removeView(addOne);


                }
            });

            container.addView(addOne);
                textOut.setId(i++);  }});
```

so, if I add an EditText, the Id will be `0` and if I add another EditText, the Id will be `1` .. etc

so, the user can select how many EditText he want, right ?

if the user add `3` EditText for example

How can my code knows ?

for example, if I want sum all the values of EditText, and the user add `3` EditTixt

I will do this

```
( EditText one = (EditText)findViewById(0) ) + ( EditText dodo  =  (EditText)findViewById(1) ) + ( EditText dodo = (EditText)findViewById(2) )
```

But, if I don't know how many EditTixt the user will add !
what can I do ?

thank you.

Comment: Have for loop instead of adding seperately

Comment: Your app actually already knows how many `EditText` the user adds from `static int i`. You just need the loop (e.g. `for-loop`). Edit: by the way, you know that your code to add the value of `EditText` is not correct, right?

Comment: @AndrewT. thank you bro, actually I do that, `EditText one = (EditText)findViewById(0);String one_1 = one.getText().toString();`

Comment: @AndrewT. tell me if it's wrong and I will be thankful.

Comment: Nah, you're doing better with this code ;) I was just afraid that you tried to *straightly add EditText*, not it's value... cheers!

Comment: @AndrewT. Hehe, you shock me. Any way, thank you man.

Answer (score 0):

```
int count = 0;
int childcount = container.getChildCount();
for (int i=0; i < childcount; i++){
      View v = container.getChildAt(i);
      if(view.getTag.equals("edittext"){
       count ++;
     }

}
```

and change this line in your code

```
final View addOne = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
  addOne.setTag("edittext");
```

count return you total edittext added by user

Comment: First time I add an EditText, your code tells me I add `2` EditText !!, but if I delete the EditText, and add it again, your code tells me I add `1` which it's right. why !

Comment: everything OK, but when I write `Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this , count + "",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` , gave me an error ! when I run the program

Answer (score 0):

take look  on this code it will count edit text for you in your layout container

first you need to making changed in your code like this and it worked with me fine :

```
 final ViewGroup addOne = (ViewGroup) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.test, null);

int count = 0 ; 
    for (int i = 0; i < addOne .getChildCount(); i++) {

        if(addOne .getChildAt(i).getClass().getSimpleName().equals("EditText"))
            count ++ ;
    }
```

Comment: it gives me `0` every time, I do not know why !

Comment: in your code you attach the edittext for addOne  view so you just need to change addOne instead of container in code above

Comment: it gives me a wrong message, maby because `getChildCount()` use just for layout ?

Comment: getChildCount used for Viewgroup you need to cast your parent to viewgroup till you can iterate throw it

Comment: ummmm, is that hard ? if it's, I don't want to waste your time.

Comment: never mind i will provide you with some code , but i need to post your layout and full code , to can edit in it

Comment: I confuse, because I used the variable `i` before, and you use it now. Anyway thank you.